# How do I select the last five games for each team and determine win/loss/tie?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is possible with PHP, but is there a way to do it with just MySQL?

I have this database:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| id | hometeam    | awayteam    | homescore  | awayscore  |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | turtles     | muffins     | 7          | 6          |
| 2  | cheetos     | snakes      | 8          | 1          |
| 3  | muffins     | raspberries | 1          | 5          |
| 4  | raspberries | snakes      | 9          | 9          |
| 5  | muffins     | cheetos     | 2          | 9          |
| 6  | turtles     | snakes      | 5          | 9          |
| 7  | snakes      | turtles     | 7          | 2          |
| 8  | muffins     | raspberries | 6          | 5          |
| 9  | turtles     | cheetos     | 6          | 1          |
| 10 | cheetos     | snakes      | 4          | 1          |
| 11 | muffins     | raspberries | 1          | 5          |
| 12 | raspberries | cheetos     | 4          | 1          |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

**I am trying to output the last five games (by id desc) for each team:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| id | team        | game1 | game2 | game3 | game4 | game5 |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | raspberries | win   | win   | loss  | tie   | win   |
| 2  | cheetos     | loss  | win   | loss  | win   | win   |
| 3  | muffins     | loss  | win   | loss  | loss  | loss  |
| 4  | snakes      | loss  | win   | win   | tie   | loss  |
| 5  | turtles     | win   | loss  | loss  | win   |       |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to pivot - check out for example: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Comment: Issues of data display are generally best resolved in the presentation layer. What's wrong with PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option from a purely academic perspective.

**1.** Get the list of teams.

```
select hometeam team
from   games
union
select awayteam team
from   games
```

Intermediate results:

```
+-------------+
| team        |
+-------------+
| turtles     |
| cheetos     |
| muffins     |
| raspberries |
| snakes      |
+-------------+
```

**2.** Get up to the last 5 games per team, starting with the oldest.

```
select team,
       -- Adjust the game numbers when number of games is less
       -- than 5.
       case when count(distinct g5.id) = 1 then min(g5.id)
            when count(distinct g4.id) = 1 then min(g4.id)
            when count(distinct g3.id) = 1 then min(g3.id)
            when count(distinct g2.id) = 1 then min(g2.id)
            when count(distinct g1.id) = 1 then min(g1.id)
       end g1,
       case when count(distinct g4.id) = 2 then min(g4.id)
            when count(distinct g3.id) = 2 then min(g3.id)
            when count(distinct g2.id) = 2 then min(g2.id)
            when count(distinct g1.id) = 2 then min(g1.id)
       end g2,
       case when count(distinct g3.id) = 3 then min(g3.id)
            when count(distinct g2.id) = 3 then min(g2.id)
            when count(distinct g1.id) = 3 then min(g1.id)
       end g3,
       case when count(distinct g2.id) = 4 then min(g2.id)
            when count(distinct g1.id) = 4 then min(g1.id)
       end g4,
       case when count(distinct g1.id) = 5 then min(g1.id)
       end g5
from(      
    select hometeam team
    from   games
    union
    select awayteam team
    from   games
) t
-- Join to the games table N times for N number of games, starting with
-- most recent (g1) to oldest (g5)
left join games g1 on (t.team in (g1.hometeam, g1.awayteam))
left join games g2 on (t.team in (g2.hometeam, g2.awayteam) and g1.id < g2.id)
left join games g3 on (t.team in (g3.hometeam, g3.awayteam) and g2.id < g3.id)
left join games g4 on (t.team in (g4.hometeam, g4.awayteam) and g3.id < g4.id)
left join games g5 on (t.team in (g5.hometeam, g5.awayteam) and g4.id < g5.id)
group by team
```

Intermediate results:

```
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+
| team        | g1   | g2   | g3   | g4   | g5   |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+
| cheetos     |   12 |   10 |    9 |    5 |    2 |
| muffins     |   11 |    8 |    5 |    3 |    1 |
| raspberries |   12 |   11 |    8 |    4 |    3 |
| snakes      |   10 |    7 |    6 |    4 |    2 |
| turtles     |    9 |    7 |    6 |    1 | NULL |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

**3.** Determine the result of each game.

```
select team,
case when team = g1.hometeam and g1.homescore > g1.awayscore then 'win'
                  when team = g1.hometeam and g1.homescore < g1.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g1.awayteam and g1.homescore > g1.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g1.awayteam and g1.homescore < g1.awayscore then 'win'
                  when g1.id is null then null
                  else 'tie' end
                  game1,
case when team = g2.hometeam and g2.homescore > g2.awayscore then 'win'
                  when team = g2.hometeam and g2.homescore < g2.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g2.awayteam and g2.homescore > g2.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g2.awayteam and g2.homescore < g2.awayscore then 'win'
                  when g2.id is null then null
                  else 'tie' end
                  game2,
case when team = g3.hometeam and g3.homescore > g3.awayscore then 'win'
                  when team = g3.hometeam and g3.homescore < g3.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g3.awayteam and g3.homescore > g3.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g3.awayteam and g3.homescore < g3.awayscore then 'win'
                  when g3.id is null then null
                  else 'tie' end
                  game3,
case when team = g4.hometeam and g4.homescore > g4.awayscore then 'win'
                  when team = g4.hometeam and g4.homescore < g4.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g4.awayteam and g4.homescore > g4.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g4.awayteam and g4.homescore < g4.awayscore then 'win'
                  when g4.id is null then null
                  else 'tie' end
                  game4,
case when team = g5.hometeam and g5.homescore > g5.awayscore then 'win'
                  when team = g5.hometeam and g5.homescore < g5.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g5.awayteam and g5.homescore > g5.awayscore then 'loss'
                  when team = g5.awayteam and g5.homescore < g5.awayscore then 'win'
                  when g5.id is null then null
                  else 'tie' end
                  game5
from(
    select team,
           case when count(distinct g5.id) = 1 then min(g5.id)
                when count(distinct g4.id) = 1 then min(g4.id)
                when count(distinct g3.id) = 1 then min(g3.id)
                when count(distinct g2.id) = 1 then min(g2.id)
                when count(distinct g1.id) = 1 then min(g1.id)
           end g1,
           case when count(distinct g4.id) = 2 then min(g4.id)
                when count(distinct g3.id) = 2 then min(g3.id)
                when count(distinct g2.id) = 2 then min(g2.id)
                when count(distinct g1.id) = 2 then min(g1.id)
           end g2,
           case when count(distinct g3.id) = 3 then min(g3.id)
                when count(distinct g2.id) = 3 then min(g2.id)
                when count(distinct g1.id) = 3 then min(g1.id)
           end g3,
           case when count(distinct g2.id) = 4 then min(g2.id)
                when count(distinct g1.id) = 4 then min(g1.id)
           end g4,
           case when count(distinct g1.id) = 5 then min(g1.id)
           end g5
    from(      
        select hometeam team
        from   games
        union
        select awayteam team
        from   games
    ) t
    left join games g1 on (t.team in (g1.hometeam, g1.awayteam))
    left join games g2 on (t.team in (g2.hometeam, g2.awayteam) and g1.id < g2.id)
    left join games g3 on (t.team in (g3.hometeam, g3.awayteam) and g2.id < g3.id)
    left join games g4 on (t.team in (g4.hometeam, g4.awayteam) and g3.id < g4.id)
    left join games g5 on (t.team in (g5.hometeam, g5.awayteam) and g4.id < g5.id)
    group by team
) r
left join games g1 on (r.g1 = g1.id)
left join games g2 on (r.g2 = g2.id)
left join games g3 on (r.g3 = g3.id)
left join games g4 on (r.g4 = g4.id)
left join games g5 on (r.g5 = g5.id)
order by team
```

Results:

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| team        | game1 | game2 | game3 | game4 | game5 |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| cheetos     | loss  | win   | loss  | win   | win   |
| muffins     | loss  | win   | loss  | loss  | loss  |
| raspberries | win   | win   | loss  | tie   | win   |
| snakes      | loss  | win   | win   | tie   | loss  |
| turtles     | win   | loss  | loss  | win   | NULL  |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Nice solution! Vote up!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 Convert it to simpler structure

```
----------------------------------
| id |     team    | result      |
----------------------------------
| 1  | turtles     | win         |
| 1  | muffins     | lost        |
| 2  | cheetos     | win         |
| 2  | snakes      | lost        |
| 3  | muffins     | lost        |
| 3  | raspberries | win         |
...
```

Something like this

```
select id,
       case rowGen.flat
       when 0 then hometeam
       else awayteam 
       end   as team,

       case rowGen.flat
       when 0 and homescore < awayscore then 'win'
       when 0 and homescore > awayscore then 'lost'
       when 1 and homescore < awayscore then 'lost'
       when 1 and homescore > awayscore then 'win'
       end   as result,
from the_table, 
     (select 0 as flag
      union all
      select 1 as flag) as rowGen
```

Then step 2. Move the query above as a subselect to FROM. Add group_concat function to group results and cut it to leave the last 5. (you can add proper order by id to group_concat)

```
----------------------------------------
| team        | last_5                 |
----------------------------------------
| raspberries | win,lost,win,win,lost  | 
| cheetos     | win,lost,lost,win,lost |
```

The select should be like this

```
select team,
       substring_index(group_concat(sub.result SEPARATOR ','), ',', 5) as last_5
from (step 1 subquery) s sub
group by team
```

Step 3. Split if necessary the `last_5` field into 5 different fields using `substring_index` of `','`.